# Is there any way that can help determine the flow direction of a river in a satellite image (Landsat)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, remote-sensing, google-earth, landsat, hydrology

For example, there is a stream in the following image, but I find it difficult to determine the flow direction of the stream. Should it be from south to north, or the opposite?

[image]

Comment: From the angles of some of the junctions I'd say S to N. Streams tend to join, not fork, and the joins tend to be at shallow angles. Most easily seen top left. But if you want to do this computationally you need to digitise the stream and tributaries or - and this might be easier - get the digital elevation model for the area and remember water flows downhill.

Answer (score 1):

For interpreting river directions from imagery or topographic maps, I'd generally recommend The Rule of V's [as described by Leveson](http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/geology/leveson/core/linksa/v_rule2.html).

On maps, you generally have two types of V's.

- Brown V's, as seen on contours. These points upstream. These are generally caused by erosion.
- Blue V's, as seen where rivers join. These point downstream.

On the image below, I've highlighted Blue V's in the red circles, and in the blue circle is a hydroelectric dam, which clearly indicates the flow direction in the area.
[image: Illustration with highlighted features]

All in all, the Chishui River flows northwest here, until it meets the Yangtze.